# Why does updating a non-existing firestore document never fails?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

```
    try
    {
        val badUserDocRef = Firebase.firestore.document("user241uyir/1")
        badUserDocRef.update("favorites", FieldValue.arrayUnion(quoteId))

        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully favorited quote: $shortQuote ")
        true
    } catch (e: Exception)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to favorite quote:$shortQuote ")

        Log.d(TAG, "e.message: ${e.message}")
        Log.d(TAG, "$e")
        false
    }
```

Neither the collection, nor the document specified in the first line exists. But when I update that document, there is no exception thrown.

Comment: So you say that "user241uyir/1" does not exist? Besides that, how do you check for an Exception?

Comment: The code you show here isn't checking for errors at all, so it could be failing and you'd never know.  Please edit the question to be more clear about what isn't working the way you expect, and how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: update() should fail if the document doesn't exist. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update

Comment: I apologize, it was a mistake on my part. My code wasn't waiting for the the task returned by update to finish, which is why exception couldn't be caught. I added **.await()** on the returned task, and as expected, the exception was caught.

Comment: So, everything is working as you expect, and you no longer have a question outstanding?

Comment: If you found the solution, please write an answer, this will help other users with same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code wasn't waiting for the the task returned by update to finish, which is why exception couldn't be caught. I added `.await()` on the returned task, and as expected, the exception was caught.

```
badUserDocRef.update("favorites", FieldValue.arrayUnion(quoteId)).await()
```

Or a listener can also be used:

```
val badUserDocRef = Firebase.firestore.document("user241uyir/1")
badUserDocRef.update("favorites", FieldValue.arrayUnion(quoteId))
    .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e) }
```

can also be used to catch the exception, if any.